# Failed to retrieve the table information with function call via DolphinDB Java API

Tags: java, dolphindb

I'm trying to call getDFSTablesByDatabase through java API in DolphinDB to obtain the table information.

[image]

But when I ran the code it failed to obtain the expected information.

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Is a good practice to paste your code instead of putting an image, as it is easier both to read and fiddle around with it! And, if you got time, I would invite you to read this post about "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made two corrections to your code:

1. Assigned the replaced value to "database" because the string method
   does not make in-place changes. Use `database=database.replace()`
2. Changed the vector to scalar type, namely change `BasicStringVector`
   to `BasicString` in this case.

The modified code is as follows:

```
String database = "[dfs://valuedb]";
database = database.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
List<Entity> arguments = new ArrayList<>(1);
BasicString y = new BasicString(database);
arguments.add(y);
BasicStringVector o1 = (BasicStringVector)conn.run("getDFSTablesByDatabase",arguments);
System.out.println(o1.getString());
```